# .waf configure returns 'Checking for header boost/format.hpp : not found' error

Tags: software-installation

i am trying to install patchage 1.0.4 from [this website](https://drobilla.net/software/patchage.html) and './waf configure' returns this error.
Also m new to linux so i don't understand much.
[this is a pic of the error statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CrUk.png)

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For latest Ubuntu 21.04 you have to use the following commands to get all dependencies and compile patchage application:

```
sudo apt-get install python-is-python3 libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-dev libglibmm-2.4-dev libgtkmm-2.4-dev libganv-dev libjack-dev libasound2-dev libboost1.74-dev libfmt-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://download.drobilla.net/patchage-1.0.4.tar.bz2
tar -xf patchage-1.0.4.tar.bz2
cd patchage-1.0.4
./waf configure
./waf
sudo ./waf install
```